# TextView inside a table cell fo tableview not displaying correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am now followind maybe a bit obsolete tutorial from `iOS Apprentice` regarding geolocation.

Anyway the job to be done seems extremly easy: 
placing `text view` inside `table view cell`. On storyboard everything looks greate but when I run it, it looks like presented on picture below (the textview covers the below category table cell view item):

[image]

I have following settings:

[image]

What is the best way to keep textview inside the table view cell and text just wraps, and overllay-y (so it is called in CSS - I am newbie to iOS) will be added to textview?

Comment: Use a UILabel with number of lines = 0,  UITextView is for displaying and editing text.

Comment: In fact it will be place where user should put his description, so this has to be editable.

Comment: Use auto layout, and pin the top and bottom of the text view to the top and bottom of the cell (with whatever padding you want).

Comment: Are you manipulating the cell height at all? If so can we see the code for it?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @railwayparade you should use

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Use heightForRowAtIndexPath to calculate the size the cell needs to be

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // replace "THE_TEXT" with the text you are displaying and "TEXT_LABEL_FONT" with the font you're using in the cell

    CGSize size = ["THE_TEXT" sizeWithFont:"TEXT_LABEL_FONT" constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.table.bounds.size.width, HUGE_VALF) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    return size.height;
}
```

You might want to subclass UITableViewCell and override layoutSubviews to set the textLabel to the exact right size, and add padding as you see fit

```
-(void)layoutSubviews // in your UITableViewCell subclass
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,self.contentView.bounds.size.width,self.contentView.bounds.size.height);
}
```

Don't forget if you do add padding on the width in layout subviews, you'll have to change the constrained width in heightForRowAtIndexPath